# Raspberry pi's pins state at boot unknown

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I would like to know, Is there a way to define a known state for the GPIO pins in my raspberry pi at boot. The issue is that whenever I boot-up my pi, it enables all of its pins and then grounds them, this really messes up the states of whatever is connected to those pins.

Answer (score 1):

"whenever I boot-up my pi, it enables all of its pins and then grounds them"

No it doesn't. On boot ALL pins are INPUTS; pins 0-8 have pullup, others pull down.

Rather than being "unknown" the state is well defined.

Depending on what you configure in config.txt you can change shortly after boot.